# UWP How to resolve error when packaging my app for the microsoft store

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, wack

hello I am having errors when creating packages of applications after associating the data of the reserved names and creating the package to go up to the store, the same thing always happens, I already have many failed projects, please help,

more complete detail in the image:

[image]

Comment: Share your WACK report please.

Comment: please here: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=certif+result.html

Comment: not a valid link, try to create link from share button if you are using dropbox

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/03cmccl6yqxzq90/certif%20result.html?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration in the Package.appxmanifest file seems not correct.There are two ways for you to fill the element.

**Method 1**:
You could **associate** the app with Store which will automatically download the following values to your local app package manifest file, named Package.appxmanifest.Package display name/Package name/Publisher ID/Publisher display name.

Steps for association:Solution Explorer(right-click) >Store > Associate App with the Store >  Next>  Select an app name for this package> App Name > Next> Associate. You could refer to [Associate your app with the Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/step-1--create-a-uwp-device-app#associate-your-app-with-the-microsoft-store) for more details.

**Method 2**:You could fill your configuration as my picture shown manually.Here is my image(Different colors mark different elements):[image]

Comment: I will try it and have it go